# How to list my OpenID provider on relying parties' login pages?

Tags: openid, google-openid

**Is there any registration process to be an openid provider**

> I'm developed an openid provider and I want to show it as an openid
>   provider in all openid supported websites

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing.  Being an openid provider is not something magic -- other sites have to specifically implement trust in you.  There is no central place where you submit your system and have it appear as an option on other people's websites.  For the most part, sites that have a hard time getting people to signup, implement openid in order to allow people with existing accounts on other well known sites to skip the signup process by trusting well known providers like Google, Yahoo, Twitter or AOL. There is no chance that any of those sites are going to reciprocate that trust to your site.